# Linking to lib on Linux without headers

Tags: c++, linux, linkage

Hello I'm trying to link to a library without headers. I wrote prototype exactly as defined in library, but ld cannot link it.

readelf -Ws Release/libcef.so  | grep KeyStringToDomKey

```
386822: 00000000066d73d0   328 FUNC    LOCAL  HIDDEN    17 _ZN2ui16KeycodeConverter17KeyStringToDomKeyERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE
```

readelf -Ws main-6cf4e2.o  | grep KeyStringToDomKey

```
  13: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN2ui16KeycodeConverter17KeyStringToDomKeyERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "domkey.h"

namespace ui {
    class KeycodeConverter {
    public:
        static DomKey KeyStringToDomKey(const std::string&);
    };
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto t = ui::KeycodeConverter::KeyStringToDomKey("t");
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***link to a library without headers*** what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `386822: 00000000066d73d0   328 FUNC    LOCAL  HIDDEN    17 _ZN2u...`

`HIDDEN` is the *key* here: this symbol is *not visible* outside of the shared library (neither to static linker `/usr/bin/ld`, nor to the dynamic loader).